# Spring security login and logout

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to make a web application using spring security, but I feel something is wrong, or missing.

Here are my codes:

security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login" login-page="/login.htm"
        username-parameter="userName" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/index.htm" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?auth=fail" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/login?out=1"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="drs" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="dr" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage() {
        return "logoutPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "loginPage";
    }
}
```

login.jsp:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
    <c:if test="${not empty param.err}">
        <div>
            <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty param.out}">
        <div>You've logged out successfully.</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty param.time}">
        <div>You've been logged out due to inactivity.</div>
    </c:if>

    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userName" value="" />
    <br>
    <br> Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input value="Login" name="submit" type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

logout.jsp:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login.htm">Login</a>
```

This work just fine, the only problem is when I hit the logout does nothing, I still have the permission which i had after the login.Normally it should be back to the login screen, asking the user to authenticate to access that page. What am I missing?

And one more problem I couldn't figured out. When I change at the login form the:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
```

to:

```
<form name='loginform' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
```

I get an error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /Dronomy_2.1/j_spring_security_check

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You aren't going to `/logout.htm` when clicking your link, you are basically never logging out. Your `login-processing-url` property is set to `/login` so when submitting the form you need to submit to `/login` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the security.xml in

```
<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/listUsers.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/play.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.htm" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        username-parameter="userName" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/index.htm" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?auth=fail" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/login.htm" />
</http>
```

added

```
</c:if>
                <form method="post"
                    action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
```

and removed the redirect to logout from the controller.
Now works fine ty :)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of logging out with CSRF enabled, the two key places in your code for this are:

```
logout-url="/logout.htm"
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I'm guessing you don't need to provide a logout page yourself.  To perform the logout you need the user's browser to perform a POST to /logout.htm.  In this POST you need to include your csrf values.  This POST is to the spring security end point you configured with logout-url="/logout.htm", and not the logout in your controller.

The [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html) provides a couple of options on how you can do this.  One is to include a form in all the pages your user can logout from, and submit the form with Javascript when the user clicks on a logout menu link.

If you do this, you can remove your request mapping I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

> This work just fine, the only problem is when i hit the logout does
>   nothing

You are just navigating the user to the login page. The session is not invalidated. SecurityContext object is not cleared.

You need to use spring security /j_spring_security_logout for logging the user out

```
<a href="/j_spring_security_logout">LogOut</a>
```

Checkout this [example](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/spring-security-authentication-and.html)

for your login form try

```
<form name='loginform' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
```

404 error occurs generally occur due to the context path computation.

Comment: Yes and no. He reconfigured the URLs so the default URLs don't apply anymore.

Comment: Well Deinum I vaguely remember the issue, occurred with my code, the fix was the context path so just wrote in the answer :)

Comment: i see. but i user ur form i get the csrf token error :HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

And when i hit the logout button i onlye get this link : http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_logout